# Embed hyperlink in sentence for Wicket property file

Tags: java, wicket

I'm facing a situation where I want to display a link like this:
*For more information check out our FAQ.*
Where the full stop is displayed right after the link. It's seems like an Overkill to define multiple properties for this like 
E.g.
`faq.info=For more information check out our`
`faq.markup=FAQ`
`faq.href=http://www.some.very.nice.url.com`
`faq.fullstop=.`
Neither do I want to include the dot only in the html. Is it possible to insert the dot at the end or the link inbetween?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [embed components inside string messages](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket's+XHTML+tags#Wicket%27sXHTMLtags-Elementwicket:message):

```
<wicket:message key="faq.info">
  <a wicket:id="faq">
    <wicket:message key="faq.info.label"/>
  </a>
</wicket:message>


faq.info=For more information check out our ${faq}.
faq.info.label=FAQ
```

For this to work you'll have to add a link with id "faq" from your Java code.